# Get data return from call function from soap is difference language

Tags: soap, vb6, wsdl

I have my project about soap.
I can call function from wsdl successfully but the string return is "????"  which "???" is thai language.

server.php

```
<?php
require_once("lib/nusoap.php");
$server = new soap_server();
//$server->soap_defencoding = 'utf-8';
$server->decode_utf8 = false;
//$server->configureWSDL("Testing WSDL ","urn:Testing WSDL ");
$server->configureWSDL("GetInformation","urn:GetInformation");
//Create a complex type

//----------------------------------
//Add ComplexType with Array
$server->wsdl->addComplexType("ArrayOfString", 
                 "complexType", 
                 "array", 
                 "", 
                 "SOAP-ENC:Array", 
                 array(), 
                 array(array("ref"=>"SOAP-  ENC:arrayType","wsdl:arrayType"=>"xsd:string[]")), 
                 "xsd:string");  
//----------------------------------

$server->register('getInfo',array('CASE_ID' =>    'xsd:string'),array('return' => 'tns:ArrayOfString'),'urn:Info','urn:Info#getInfo');

function getInfo($case_id) {

include("ConnectSQL.php");

$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 

$strCase_ID = $case_id;
// Query
$qry = "SELECT * ";
$qry .= "FROM tbCustomer WHERE CASE_ID = '$strCase_ID' ";
//$arr[0]= $qry;
//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mssql_query($qry);
//$arr[0] = $strCase_ID;
$i = 0;
$recordcount = mssql_num_rows($result);
if ($recordcount != 0)
{

    //display the results 
    while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
    {

        $myname = $row["PREFIX"] ." ". $row["NAME"] ." ".  $row["MIDDLE"]." " ;

        $arr[$i] =  $myname;


        $i = $i+1;

    }
    //close the connection
    mssql_close($dbhandle);
    //return $myname; //iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $myname );
    return $arr;
}
else
{
    return $arr;
    //echo "<font color=red>**</font> Username & Password is wrong";
}


}

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA  : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
exit(); 
?>
```

client side:

```
Dim clnt As New SoapClient30
Dim strText
Dim strID As String

clnt.MSSoapInit "http://localhost/MyProject4/server.php?wsdl"

strID = "001"
strText = clnt.getInfo(strID) 
MsgBox strText(0)
```

I don't know way for encode from vb6 client.

thank you

Comment: Can you share some code on the calling side and the server side?

Comment: I have shared code where above

Comment: Is your server responding with `utf-8`? Why did you comment out the line with `$server->soap_defencoding`?

Comment: I tried cut comment  //$server->soap_defencoding not work.